# Запрет добавления и удаления строк DataGrid WPF

Tags: datagrid, c#, winforms, wpf

Как сделать то, что описано на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k5c88sw3(v=vs.110).aspx) для WinForms, но для WPF?

Также нужно запретить редактирование всей таблицы в DataGrid.

Answer (score 4):

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А Также нужно запретить редактирование всей таблицы в DataGrid - не подскажите?

Comment: IsReadOnly="True"